# Errorcode 22 while running mysqldump

Tags: mysql

Yesterday I run mysqldump and worked find, but today running same commad with same parameters throws an error:

> mysqldump: Error: 'Can't create/write to file 'C:\Windows\SERVIC~2\NETWOR~1\AppD
>   ata\Local\Temp#sqlb98_13b9_2.MYI' (Errcode: 22)' when trying to dump tablespaces
>
> mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'show fields from `tblinvmat`': Can't
>   create/write t o file
>   'C:\Windows\SERVIC~2\NETWOR~1\AppData\Local\Temp#sqlb98_13b9_4d.MYI'
>   (Er rcode: 22) (1)

OS: Windows Server 2012
Mysql 5.5.28

What is happening and why because by using HeidiSQL i can export database properly?

EDIT: I've tryed to see server status using MySQL Workbench but even this tool throws messageboxes with same error code.

Answer (score 1):

make sure if You do have acces to that path/file and mysql temp files dir.

Comment: I'll check that but right now I have noticed one thing; currently there is no any activity on database (no any crud operations in this moment) and I've tried to run again mysqldump and it works perfectly. Seems that it all about how many users access to database and how many files are opened it moment when i want to run mysqldump. I dont know is ti because of Windows or something else. Previous server was running WinXP and now i moved database to Win2012 R2 Server.